# how to get a rolling mean with mean from previous window

Tags: python, pandas, mean, rolling-computation

I am desperatly searching for a solution with pandas. Maybe you could help me.

I am looking for a rolling mean with consideration of the previous mean.

df looks like this:

| index | count |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 4 |
| 1 | 6 |
| 2 | 10 |
| 3 | 12 |

now, using the `rolling(window=2).mean()` function I would get something like this:

| index | count | r_mean |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 4 | NaN |
| 1 | 6 | 5 |
| 2 | 10 | 8 |
| 3 | 12 | 11 |

I would like to consider the mean from the first calculation, like this:

| index | count | r_mean |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 4 | NaN |
| 1 | 6 | 5 |
| 2 | 10 | 7.5 |
| 3 | 12 | 9.5 |

where,

```
row1: (4+6)/2=5

row2: (5+10)/2=7.5

row3: (7.5+12)/2=9.75
```

thank you in advance!

Comment: It is hard to make it vectorized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** There is actually the method [`ewm`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.ewm.html) implemented in pandas that can do this calculation

```
df['res'] = df['count'].ewm(alpha=0.5, adjust=False, min_periods=2).mean()
```

**Original answer:** Here is a way. as everything can be develop with coefficient being power of 2.

```
# first create a series with power of 2
coef = pd.Series(2**np.arange(len(df)), df.index).clip(lower=2)

df['res'] = (coef.div(2)*df['count']).cumsum()/coef

print(df)
   index  count   res
0      0      4  2.00
1      1      6  5.00
2      2     10  7.50
3      3     12  9.75
```

You can mask the first value with `df.loc[0, 'res'] = np.nan` if needed

Comment: What kind of mathematical witchcraft is this?

Comment: @ScottBoston I realized that for row2, you can rewrite the calculation as `(2**0*4+2**0*6+2**1*10)/2**2`, and row3 as `(2**0*4+2**0*6+2**1*10+ 2**2*12)/2**3`, that can be generalized with power 2 :)

Comment: Fascinating... I was looking for a solution like this a while ago.  Power of 2 series.  Diminishing impacts as you roll along the series.  I love it!

Comment: @ScottBoston there is actually an easier way using ewm ;)

Comment: Wow.... I need to keep ewm in my pocket.  Thanks @BenT

Comment: Thank you so much @Ben.T! ewm helped me directly.. how much time I've spend and it is so simple!

Comment: @dpy glad it helps :)

Answer (score 2):

We can use simple `python` loop for this , if you would like speed it up you can try `numba`

```
l= []
n = 2
for x,y in zip(df['count'],df.index):
    try :
        l.append(np.nansum(x+l[y-n+1])/n)
    except:
        l.append(x)
df.loc[n-1:, 'new']=l[n-1:]
df
Out[332]: 
   index  count   new
0      0      4   NaN
1      1      6  5.00
2      2     10  7.50
3      3     12  9.75
```